# Makefile with multiple commands

Tags: makefile

I created a Makefile which looks like:

```
test :
  python -m pytest -v test
run :
  python run.py
```

I can run `make run` which executes the command correctly. But when I run `make test` I see: `make:`test' is up to date.`

However, if I take out the `run` area, then `test` works correclty.

I can't figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Reading the documentation on how make works would solve the issue: Your targets have no dependencies, so they will be up-to-date always. Maybe describe what you want to achieve, and make the question a real question.

Comment: You have no dependencies or conditions to make the target need to be built, so everything stays up to date. You need to learn [what a makefile is and how it works](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile).

Comment: The targets won't be up to date _always_.  They'll be up to date _if the target exists_ (as a file or directory on the disk).  A target with no prerequisites is considered up to date if it exists, and out of date if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Makefile needs to look like:

```
.PHONY: test run

test:
    python -m pytest -v test

run:
    python run.py
```

The `.PHONY` line is GNU make's way of saying these particular targets don't produce any output.  The documentation on [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) is a good read, if you want more information.